# What permissions do opengauss need to grant to create a user?

Tags: open-gauss

What permissions do opengauss need to grant to create a user?

```
openGauss=# create database db_test with encoding 'utf8' template = template0;
CREATE DATABASE

openGauss=# create user hxl password 'Gauss@123456';
NOTICE: The encrypted password contains MD5 ciphertext, which is not secure.
CREATE ROLE

openGauss=#grant all privileges on database db_test to hxl;
openGauss=#grant all on schema public to hxl;

Log in with hxl user and find that the table cannot be created
[ omm@host134 data ] $ gsql - U hxl - d db_test - h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432  

db_test=> create table public.tb_test(id number,name varchar(32));
ERROR: permission denied for schema public
DETAIL: N/A
```

Why is my operation restricted?

Answer (score 0):

To grant the user full permissions to the database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db1 to usera;
```